# Duplicate tableview cells added above previously loaded cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, tableview

I have a collection view. On one of the collection cells, I have a tableview with 5 different custom cells. I am reusing each cell of the table view.

When the table is reloaded, I see new rows added just above the previously loaded cells. This appears like a new table has been added just above the previous table. I got this visual when I see the 3D view of the collection view:

[image: Screenshot]

Blue color is one of the 5 cells. Each time the table loads, it has added 5 sets of rows above previously loaded cells. What is happening here and how could this be possible?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.cabinTableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName:"CabinNetNib", bundle:
        nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: cabinNetNib)
}

internal func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellDetail = tableViewDataSourceArray[indexPath.row] as? cabinDetailsMO
    let cellType = cellDetails?.cellTypeEnum

    if cellType == CellType.Net {

        let netLabelCell = self.questionsTableView
            .dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(questionLabelCellIdentifier) as?
        NetLabelTableViewCell

        netLabelCell!.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

        netLabelCell!.netLabel.attributedText = cellDetails?.attributedQuestionString

        return netLabelCell!
    }
    else if cellType == CellType.Video {

        let videoCell = self.cabinTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cabinVideoCellIdentifier)
            as! cabinVideoTableViewCell
        videoCell.videoName = cellDetails?.questionVideo
        videoCell.loadVideoItem(cellDetails?.questionVideo, videoFields: nil)
        videoCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

        shouldReloadAllCells = true
        image_videoCellIndex = indexPath.row

        return videoCell
    }

    else if (cellType == CellType.captian) {
        let captianCell = self.cabinTableView .dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(captianCellIdentifier) as!
        CaptianTableViewCell
        captianCell .selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

        captianCell.question_idLabel.text = cellDetails?.contentidName

        return aptianCell
    }
}
```

First cell is alone a nib.

Comment: Could you show how you reload the tableView? Seems like with each reloading you add new tableView as a subview.

Comment: I guess you're dequeuing cells outside the cell for item method, show the code

Comment: I have added sample code.